# Generate a php report when submitting a form in a new page with a new url

Tags: php, html

I am trying to generate a report based on user input from a form in html. As of right now, everything works. Except when I generate the report, the url of the newly opened tab contains the location and the name of my php file. Obviously, this report won't be accessible once the user closes that tab.
Is there any way I can store this file on my server and specify a path for it(for each user)?

Or just generate a pdf file out of it? I tried using some libraries but they don't fully support bootstrap.

Comment: Hide what? `test.php`? It is seen in `action` attribute already.

Comment: you may have to use some JS here. PHP can't open a new tab on the server side. You could use Ajax to submit the form and once the report is generated make the ajax function open a new tab with the report.

Comment: Edited the original question...